# Transaction (Process ID 84) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have developed a Monitoring application. So there i have used a Timer function in order to check some values in a SQL Table.

though there are so many function it gives an following error for one function called getLogEntry()

```
message>Transaction (Process ID 84) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.</message>
<innerMessage>
</innerMessage>
<source>.Net SqlClient Data Provider</source>
<stackTrace>at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at ShiftAlertSystem.DBAccess.getLogEntry(Int32 nEventLogIdn, connections cn)</stackTrace>
    <createdAt>2012/06/18 13:10:47</createdAt>
```

This is the implementation of the function

```
public LogEntry getLogEntry(int nEventLogIdn, connections cn)
    {
        lock (_objLock)
        {
            LogEntry lgEntObj = new LogEntry();
             SqlConnection NewCon3 = new SqlConnection();
             SqlCommand newCmd2 = null;
             SqlDataReader dr = null;

             try
             {


                 string connectString;
                 // Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.u
                 string DataSource = cryptIT.Decrypt(cn.DataSource_bio);
                 string initialCatalog = cryptIT.Decrypt(cn.InitialCatalog_bio);
                 string user = cryptIT.Decrypt(cn.user_bio);
                 string password = cryptIT.Decrypt(cn.password_bio);
                 bool intergratedSecurity = cn.IntegratedSecurity_bio;

                 if (intergratedSecurity)
                 {
                     connectString = "Data Source=" + DataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + initialCatalog + ";Integrated Security=True";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     connectString = "Data Source=" + DataSource + ";Initial Catalog=" + initialCatalog + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + password;
                 }

                 NewCon3 = new SqlConnection(connectString);
                 NewCon3.Open();



                 newCmd2 = NewCon3.CreateCommand();
                 newCmd2.Connection = NewCon3;
                 newCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                 newCmd2.CommandText = @"
                                 SELECT [nUserID]
                                        ,[sUserName]
                                        ,dateadd(s,[nDateTime],'1970/1/1') AS LogDateTime
                                        ,[nEventIdn]
                                        ,[nTNAEvent]
                                        ,[TB_READER].[nReaderIdn]
                                        ,[sName]
                                 FROM 
                                        [TB_EVENT_LOG]
                                        ,[TB_USER]
                                        ,[TB_READER]
                                WHERE 

                                        [nEventLogIdn] = " + nEventLogIdn +
                                         @" AND
                                        [TB_EVENT_LOG].[nUserID] = [TB_USER].[sUserID]
                                        AND
                                        [nFlag]= 1
                                        AND
                                        [TB_EVENT_LOG].[nReaderIdn]=[TB_READER].[nReaderIdn]"
                                         ;
                 dr = newCmd2.ExecuteReader();

                 if (dr != null && dr.Read())
                 {
                     lgEntObj.nUserID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                     lgEntObj.nUserName = dr.GetString(1);
                     lgEntObj.LogDateTime = dr.GetDateTime(2);
                     lgEntObj.nEventIdn = dr.GetInt32(3);
                     lgEntObj.nTNAEvent = dr.GetInt16(4);
                     lgEntObj.nReaderIdn = dr.GetInt32(5);
                     lgEntObj.sName = dr.GetString(6);
                 }
                 dr.Close();
                 newCmd2.Dispose();
                 // NewCon.Close();
                 NewCon3.Close();

                 return lgEntObj;
             }
             catch (Exception exc)
             {
                 CenUtility.ErrorLog.CreateLog(exc);
                 return null;
             }

             finally
             {
                 if (dr != null)
                     dr.Close(); 

                 if(newCmd2 != null)
                     newCmd2.Dispose();


                     NewCon3.Close();


             }


        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to consider the suggestions made in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382410/sql-server-deadlock-fix-force-join-order-or-automatically-retry. We've successfully implemented query retries if the original query is deadlocked.

Comment: Also, how many log entries are you writing? If you are writing a lot, it may be that you are just impeding the SELECT with a large number of INSERTS.

Comment: By this application nothing is written into those tables, but another Software writes data into those tables.

Comment: Please get the deadlock graph and add this to your question. If you are on 2008 [you can get this from the default Extended Events trace](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql/10646#10646) otherwise you will need to set up a trace to capture it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may want to refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382410/sql-server-deadlock-fix-force-join-order-or-automatically-retry) for some more helpful suggestions.

I use the following pattern for database retries; in this instance, we return a DataTable but the pattern is the same regardless; you detect a SqlDeadlock or Timeout based on the SqlException [Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx), and retry, up to a maximum number of n times.

```
    public DataTable DoSomeSql(int retryCount = 1)
    {
        try
        {
            //Run Stored Proc/Adhoc SQL here

        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            if (retryCount == MAX_RETRY_COUNT) //5, 7, Whatever
            {
                log.Error("Unable to DoSomeSql, reached maximum number of retries.");
                throw;
            }

            switch (sqlEx.Number)
            {
                case DBConstants.SQL_DEADLOCK_ERROR_CODE: //1205
                    log.Warn("DoSomeSql was deadlocked, will try again.");
                    break;
                case DBConstants.SQL_TIMEOUT_ERROR_CODE: //-2
                    log.Warn("DoSomeSql was timedout, will try again.");
                    break;
                default:
                    log.WarnFormat(buf.ToString(), sqlEx);
                    break;
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //Can also use Math.Rand for a random interval of time
            return DoSomeSql(asOfDate, ++retryCount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do hope you're monitoring this.  If, for example, you get one deadlock retry every million queries, or per month, then you're fine.  If you get 1 every minute, or every other query, then you're in trouble and should fix the cause rather than working around it...

Comment: @Dems Sometimes you get a deadlock but you don't want your application to die because of it; retrying buys you the time you need to investigate the root cause of the problem; note that I do suggest reading the first link :-) Sometimes you also get a deadlock or timeout just because the system is busy.

Comment: I'm not saying not to do this, I'm just saying to monitor it. As I said, if it's infrequent then you're good. But if it's regular then you have a problem and you have forced it into a silent failure - Good for the app at that point in time, but then means that you need some way of monitoring whether it happens so frequently that you actually need to address the underlying cause and not just it's effects.  If you don't monitor then you don't even know there is anything to investigate.

Comment: @Dems We actually got it 20 or 30 times an hour during peak loads. This approach gave me enough time to keep the system running but also to investigate the root cause as you suggest. Fixed it too :-) I totally agree with you!

Comment: Maybe retry for ***SqlException.Number***:  `SqlConnectionBroken = -1,
SqlTimeout = -2,
SqlOutOfMemory = 701,
SqlOutOfLocks = 1204,
SqlDeadlockVictim = 1205,
SqlLockRequestTimeout = 1222,
SqlTimeoutWaitingForMemoryResource = 8645,
SqlLowMemoryCondition = 8651,
SqlWordbreakerTimeout = 30053`

Comment: Can you use ***Polly*** for retries ?

Answer (score 5):

Your query deadlocked with another query.  The other query is most likely an `insert`, `update` or `delete` query, since `select` alone does not tend to deadlock.

If you don't care too much about consistency, you can use the `with (nolock)` hint:

```
FROM 
    [TB_EVENT_LOG] with (nolock)
    ,[TB_USER] with (nolock)
    ,[TB_READER] with (nolock)
```

That will cause your query not to place locks.  A query without locks will not cause deadlocks.  The downside is that it might return inconsistent data, when it runs at the same time as a modification query.

Comment: Note that if the lock has escalated to a Table Lock, this will not work; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx.

Comment: @dash: That article applies only to DDL, like `alter table`, which acquires a Sch-M (schema modification) lock.  A `with (nolock)` will happily read through a `with (tablockx)`

Comment: "Support for use of the READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints in the FROM clause that apply to the target table of an UPDATE or DELETE statement will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these hints in this context in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them." is also in that. I'm not 100% sure that it will read through a transaction in all cases; I've had situations where nolock has not worked because a tablelock has been in place.

Comment: Also, from the header of the article: Applies to:

DELETE

INSERT

SELECT

UPDATE

MERGE I'm not really disagreeing with you (hence just a comment), it's just that I've found the behavour of (NOLOCK) to be unreliable, and, as @Dems mentions, it's better to fix the underlying issue.